# How to get the sender Profile info i.e email,username and pic using GMAIL API in list

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, gmail, gmail-api

I have started creating an application in Flutter that has GMAIL API integration using the

[Googleapi's plugin from pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/googleapis)

I have almost spent bunch of months working on the [GMAIL API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference) a great success that i have achieved that i have almost integrated the GMAIL API to my application using the plugin being a new to [flutter](https://flutter.dev) ...

But still i am on searching and scratching my head to get the list of the sender on my mail i have almost used [User.threads](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/list) to get the list of the messages but the user.threads just provides the mail body not the info about the senders ...

Well i know you might be saying that use the [THREAD ID](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/get) to get the senders info well i have utilised that too...

But it a way long logic i need to make out..

I am willing to know does **GOOGLE provides some paid GMAIL API** to get the list of the senders ..

If anyone of the dev .... knows about i would be truly happy to complete my project as far as possible....

Comment: Hello @neon97, why doesn't the method of retrieving the id of the thread and then getting the specific thread doesn't work for your situation? (Using the `Users.threads: get`) Would you mind going into more details about the issues you are encountering when trying this? Cheers!

Comment: I agree with you words but i am making the list of messages just like inbox where you need to show the sender name,profile pic and latest mail where as i have made the list using User.threads list but in that response i ma just getting the mail body .. As well as i am not getting the sender name or mail id ...Thats why i am searching for a list to get everything at once ... I am aware of user.get with ID ihave used that api on clicking the mail to view all the details of the users.....

Answer (score 0):

Answering you question GOOGLE **DOES NOT** provide a paid GMAIL API different from the public one. You can indeed increase your quotas by [setting a billing account](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota). But the API endpoint and resources will stay the same.

As stated in the [Response](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/list#response_1) for the [`Users.threads.list`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/list):

> Note that each thread resource does not contain a list of messages. The list of messages for a given thread can be fetched using the threads.get method.

So you have no other option a part from making a subsequent request to the API getting the messages and info for every thread.